# Include source code of malloc.c in gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, malloc

How can I include/view the source code of `malloc` in gdb?

I want to do a step by step execution in `gdb`, and step into `malloc.c` source code when any of the malloc functions is called.

Currently what gdb says is:
`malloc.c: No such file or directory.`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220853/call-to-malloc-failing-in-gdb-session) guy here faced the same problem, but they do not mention a solution, ie how to actually step into the source code of malloc.

I am on `Ubuntu server 14.04`, and I have already tried to install the following:
`libc6-dbg`, `libc6-dev`, and `libc6-dbgsym`.
I don't even know if one of these packages might help, but installing the `libc-dbgsym` gives me the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dbgsym_2.19-0ubuntu6.6_amd64.ddeb (--unpack):  trying to overwrite
    '/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/audit/sotruss-lib.so', which
    is also in package libc6-dbg:amd64 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 dpkg-deb: error:
    subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

Comment: You need to find, or compile, a debug version of the libraries.

Comment: @MartinJames that's the part I am failing at! :(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following worked for me. Not sure whether there is a better way.

1. Install libc6-dbg (which you have already done):
   `sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg`
2. Install the eglibc-source package (ubuntu actually uses eglibc): `sudo apt-get install eglibc-source`.
3. Unpack the tar file that was installed in /usr/src/glibc: `/usr/src/glibc $ sudo tar xvf eglibc-2.19.tar.xz`
4. Crank up gdb and add in the path to the malloc source: `(gdb) dir /usr/src/glibc/eglibc-2.19/malloc`

> (gdb) n
>
> 13          char *c = malloc(100);
>
> (gdb) s
>
> __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=100) at malloc.c:2876 2876
>
> {
>
> (gdb)

Comment: Works like charm! Also, step 4 can be added in `.gdbinit`!

Comment: Great! One somewhat related gotcha (which it sounds like you know about). But for future readers: Don't break on `malloc` itself as libc does all sorts of symbol gymnastics so that the `malloc` symbol is not the actual `malloc` that is invoked. Instead break in  the caller and step into the `malloc` call.

Comment: For `Ubuntu 18.04` users, seems that `eglibc-source` isn't a thing anymore. Seems to just be `glibc-source` now, based on my search through the repos.

Answer (score 3):

Gdb can only show the source codes because the debug-compiled binaries contain references between the binary code and the source files.

`malloc()` is in the C library. On normal systems, it is not compiled with debug metadata, and its sources are also not installed in the system.

But they are reachable, you only need to install the debug versions of these libraries. For example, on debian an `apt-get install glibc-debug` or similar will do it. On SuSE, a `zipper in libc6-debug` (afaik, maybe the exact package names could be a little bit differ).

Comment: I should have downvoted just because you said "gdb is not a wizard"!

Comment: Jokes aside, I think I did that. I am on Ubuntu, and I believe `libc6-dbg` is the equivalent of what you suggested!

Comment: @Paschalis I am sorry, I didn't have any negative intention with that. I removed this from the answer.

Comment: I was joking :) I 've installed a debug version of the libc. Still does not work! I 've updated my question a while ago!

Comment: @Paschalis Is the glibc source also on your system? Can you see its files? It is big.

Comment: I have installed the `eglibc-source` package, but I haven't found the source yet on the machine. Also, still gdb does not find src of `malloc.c`