# How to retrieve arguments of a function in gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

I wrote a simple crack-me program. You see the assembly code of a function named `check` inside this program:

```
(gdb) disassemble check 
Dump of assembler code for function check:
   0x08048484 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x08048485 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048487 <+3>: sub    esp,0x28
   0x0804848a <+6>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x0
   0x08048491 <+13>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x0
   0x08048498 <+20>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x0804849b <+23>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x0804849e <+26>:    call   0x8048384 <strlen@plt>      <<<<<< Here!
   0x080484a3 <+31>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
   0x080484a6 <+34>:    jae    0x80484fb <check+119>
   0x080484a8 <+36>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
   0x080484ab <+39>:    add    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x080484ae <+42>:    movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [eax]
   0x080484b1 <+45>:    mov    BYTE PTR [ebp-0xd],al
   0x080484b4 <+48>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x4]
   0x080484b7 <+51>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],eax
   0x080484bb <+55>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x8048638
   0x080484c3 <+63>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0xd]
   0x080484c6 <+66>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x080484c9 <+69>:    call   0x80483a4 <sscanf@plt>
   0x080484ce <+74>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x080484d1 <+77>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x8]
   0x080484d4 <+80>:    add    DWORD PTR [eax],edx
   0x080484d6 <+82>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0xf
   0x080484da <+86>:    jne    0x80484f4 <check+112>
   0x080484dc <+88>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x804863b
   0x080484e3 <+95>:    call   0x8048394 <printf@plt>
   0x080484e8 <+100>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x0
   0x080484ef <+107>:   call   0x80483b4 <exit@plt>
   0x080484f4 <+112>:   lea    eax,[ebp-0xc]
   0x080484f7 <+115>:   inc    DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x080484f9 <+117>:   jmp    0x8048498 <check+20>
   0x080484fb <+119>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048649
   0x08048502 <+126>:   call   0x8048394 <printf@plt>
   0x08048507 <+131>:   leave  
   0x08048508 <+132>:   ret
```

As you see above, inside the `check` function, there is a function call to `strlen`. The question is how can I see the string that is passed to `strlen()`?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955609/include-source-code-of-malloc-c-in-gdb

Comment: The answer already appears in your log, the instruction call 0x8048384 <strlen@plt> means that there is a syscall made to strlen with argument stored at the address 0x8048384 (in the stack). You have to examine the stack from address 0x8048384 until you find '\0' to get the argument passed to strlen.

Comment: @shamba No, `0x8048384` is address of start of the `strlen` function.

Comment: `x/s $eax` (or is it `p/s`?)

Comment: @Jester `x/s $eax`. Thanks. Another question appeared here! How does $eax can contains strings larger than eax size? And where does second and third , ... arguments stored? (if any)

Comment: `eax` just holds a pointer to the string (do you know C?). Note that actually the arguments are in memory on the stack at `[esp]`, just that in this piece of code it's also in `eax` so it was more convenient than having to read it from the stack.