# Get source code for libc for debugging in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, glibc

I am currently debugging an api from shared library libc6 using gdb

`getaddrinfo()`

which is being called from python module:

`socket.getaddrinfo()`

I have managed to set a breakpoint at getaddrinfo.c and I wish to navigate the execution in single steps.

**Source files:**

`ldd --version`

tells that I have glibc 2.19, and I have downloaded the source from here

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/

But during single step debugging using gdb, it doesnt look like the line numbers are matching.

Is there a cleaner way to download the source for libc6

PS: I am new to gdb debugging, please do point out any needed info.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated and the solution depends on your distribution. What distribution (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04) do you use?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955609/include-source-code-of-malloc-c-in-gdb the first answer, up to and including point 3. The debug versions get installed in `/usr/lib/debug/lib/` but GDB should be aware of that.

Comment: sudo apt-get install eglibc-source was the thing I was looking for. Thanks a ton!! You can post this as answer below, I will accept it.
BTW I wonder why the source code which I browse using sudo apt-get install eglibc-source is different than what I downloaded from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/

Comment: Just a quick note: `getaddrinfo` (and other name resolution routines) in GLIBC are effectively un-debuggable: the code is *very* convoluted.

Comment: The Trusty package is `apt install glibc-source`. `eglibc-source` is not a package.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi gdb) s
_IO_puts (str=0x4005c4 "Hello world!") at ioputs.c:33
(gdb) i line
Line 1 of "ioputs.c" is at address 0x7ffff7a7c6a0 <_IO_puts> but contains no code.

Comment: @CSQGB yes, that can happen. As I said at teh very beginning: it's a bit more complicated and that's a polite way to state that fact. You might give it a try and formulate a full question according to the rules to post here..

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 22.04 minimal runnable example**

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/487222/how-to-install-debug-symbols-for-installed-packages/1434174#1434174

In the case of glibc, the debug symbols already appear to come preinstalled, otherwise we would need to get them with:

```
printf "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com %s main restricted universe multiverse\n" $(lsb_release -cs){,-updates,-security,-proposed} | \
 sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
sudo apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
sudo apt update
sudo apt install coreutils-dbgsym
sudo apt install libc6-dbg
```

and then get source with:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list~
sudo sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /'
/etc/apt/sources.list sudo apt-get update
apt source libc6
```

which produces directory: `glibc-2.35`.

We then make a C hello world to test with:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello");
}
```

and compile and GDB into it with:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
gdb -ex 'set substitute-path . glibc-2.35'  main.out
```

and then test it out as:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1151: file main.c, line 4.
Starting program: /home/ciro/tmp/main.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello");
(gdb) s
__GI__IO_puts (str=0x555555556004 "hello") at ./libio/ioputs.c:33
33      {
(gdb) l
28      #include <string.h>
29      #include <limits.h>
30
31      int
32      _IO_puts (const char *str)
33      {
34        int result = EOF;
35        size_t len = strlen (str);
36        _IO_acquire_lock (stdout);
37
```

"We're in".

Some other versions of Ubuntu had sources at an absolute location like:

```
/tmp/build138741687/
```

in which case you would instead want:

```
set substitute-path /tmp/build138741687/ glibc-2.35
```