# Trying to install glibc source on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, glibc

BeIow is the source code for a C program I use to memory map files.  This program is compiled to a shared object and linked into the main program.  Its only function is to create a memory mapping for a file.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _LARGE_TIME_API
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

int64_t * create_file_mmap(const char *filename, const char *mode, int64_t *return_buffer) {

    FILE * fd = fopen(filename, mode);

    char buf[1024];

    if (fd == 0) {
        strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
        printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf); }

    int fd_I = fileno(fd);
    int64_t return_buf[2];
    
    off_t offset = 0;
    int seek_pos = fseeko(fd, offset, SEEK_END);
    off_t file_size = ftello(fd);

    double * map_ptr;
    static int64_t ret_val; //return_array[2];
    map_ptr = (double *)mmap(0, file_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd_I, 0);

     if (errno != 0) {
         strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
         printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf); }

    ret_val = (int64_t)map_ptr;

    return_buf[0] = ret_val;
    return_buf[1] = file_size;
    int64_t *return_buf_ptr = return_buf;

    fclose(fd); // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS SIGNALLED

    return return_buf_ptr; //ret_val;
}
```

I compile it with:

```
gcc -ggdb -shared -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -ldl -lc -o Memory_Map_File.o Memory_Map_File.c.
```

I run it on my local Ubuntu 20.04 (with and without GDB) and it works perfectly.  However, when I set up a temporary droplet at Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 22.04, at the line `fclose(fd)` shown above, I get this segfault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e14c70 in __GI__IO_setb (f=f@entry=0x4097c0, b=b@entry=0x0, eb=eb@entry=0x0, a=a@entry=0) at ./libio/genops.c:338
338     ./libio/genops.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7e14c70 in __GI__IO_setb (f=f@entry=0x4097c0, b=b@entry=0x0, eb=eb@entry=0x0, 
    a=a@entry=0) at ./libio/genops.c:338
#1  0x00007ffff7e12f55 in _IO_new_file_close_it (fp=fp@entry=0x4097c0)
    at ./libio/fileops.c:153
#2  0x00007ffff7e05d8f in _IO_new_fclose (fp=0x4097c0) at ./libio/iofclose.c:53
#3  0x00007ffff7d5d2b3 in create_file_mmap (
    filename=0x7ffff7fb8240 <input_fname> "/opt/P01_SH/_Test_Data/Random_Double_4000.bin", 
    mode=0x7ffff7fb826e <file_mode_input> "rb", 
    return_buffer=0x7ffff7fba0f0 <mmap_return_buffer>) at Memory_Map_File.c:48
#4  0x00007ffff7fb7044 in MMap () from /opt/P01_SH/Calc_XYZ/Calc_XYZ.so
#5  0x0000000000401280 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe448)
    at Call_Create_Threads_in_C-Calc_XYZ.c:68
```

The main issue is:  ./libio/genops.c: No such file or directory.  /libio/genops.c is part of the glibc, so my problem appears to be linking to glibc.  Here's how I link:

```
sudo nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf Calc_XYZ.asm

sudo ld -shared Calc_XYZ.o /opt/P01_SH/_Debug_Wrappers_in_C/Create_Threads_in_C-Calc_XYZ.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Sprintf_in_C.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Write_Data_in_C.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Timer_for_NASM.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/POSIX_Shared_Memory.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Virtual_Memory.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Available_Memory.o /opt/P01_SH/_Library/Memory_Map_File.o -ldl -lrt -lpthread -lc -o Calc_XYZ.so
```

I added `-lc` to link to glibc, but I haven't found any confirmation that that's what I should use.  Both `-libc` and `-glibc` do not work.

The problem apparently is that I need the source for ./libio/genops.c.  My research led me to Ciro Santilli's answer at [Get source code for libc for debugging in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476571/get-source-code-for-libc-for-debugging-in-gdb) where he shows code to download and install the source.  I followed his instructions line by line but at the line sudo sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' I get:  sed: no input files.

I also tried apt source glibc but I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'deb-src' URIs in your sources.list
```

Locally the glibc version is 2.31 and in the cloud it's 2.35.  I don't know why the source is not a problem locally but it is a problem in the cloud.  Locally I did no extra steps to add the glibc source when I originally built Ubuntu.  However, this is a droplet at Digital Ocean, and it comes fairly "bare" so I have to install a lot of software (e.g. gcc, nasm, etc).

So my questions are:

1. Does the segfault message I received above mean that I need the source for genops.c, and therefore need to download the source?
2. How do I download the source, in view of the message I got when I ran Ciro Santilli's code?
3. If not that, how can I solve this?
4. In the future, as I support end users with multiple versions of glibc, will I face version problem with glibc?

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: `return return_buf_ptr` - you are returning a pointer to a local array which does not exist after the function returns.

Comment: If you can successfully compile the program and it doesn't fail until you run it, the problem isn't with missing library files (unless the program uses `dlopen()` to open a library dynamically).

Comment: @Eugene Sh - return_buf is passed in from the calling program.  return_buf_ptr sets up a pointer to that buffer.  On return, the buffer is still there.

Comment: You never use the `return_buffer` parameter. I suspect you're supposed to store the return values there, not by returning a new array.

Comment: @RTC222 You're confusing `return_buffer` (the parameter) and `return_buf` (the local array).

Comment: @Barmar - the shared object is linked into another shared object and called from there.  The shared object that calls it is called by dlopen().  But it works exactly the same way locally, so my issue is not with the return buffer, but with the missing glibc source code.

Comment: `SIGSEGV` is exactly the kind of error you expect to get from returning a local array.

Comment: Then why does it work locally and not in the cloud?  Why does it specifically signal the problem at line fclose(fd) and not at the return line?  I'll try this in the cloud because that may be the issue; sometimes these segfaults are caused by issues other than the line signalled.

Comment: Because this is what "undefined behavior" is. It might look like working in some circumstances, but blow in your face in other.

Comment: Great point.  I'll be back in a short while after I try this in the cloud (I have to reinitialize the droplet, which takes a few minutes).  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I changed the final line to "return 0;" and commented out the line that creates the pointer to return_buf.  But I still get the same error at fclose(fd).

Comment: I have worked around this for now by commenting out the line "fclose(fd)" where the segfault occurs.  When an fd is for a file mapping, closing it is optional.  Also, when passing a buffer from an outside program (at least a NASM program), I had to create a pointer to that buffer to return it properly.  Now the program returns with the correct info. But I would still be very interested in any ideas on why this occurred in the first place.

Comment: 2. You add a suitable line to /etc/apt/sources or drop a file in sources.d/.  I don't use ubuntu for debian it's would be something like this "deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware".

Comment: 4. You usually setup a build environment (i.e. virtual machine) that matches each platform you want to support.  You may also be able to cross compile to your target environment.

Comment: @Allan Wind - That is what Ciro Santilli's post at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476571/get-source-code-for-libc-for-debugging-in-gdb was about, but in my post above I show what went wrong when I ran his code.  Do you know why that failed to add debian sources?

Comment: @RTC222 Sorry, I never used Ubuntu but I suggest you ask Unix & Linux or ServerFault.  All I have to do is add a suitable line then `apt udate`.  They would need to see your sources.list file.  The error message suggest you didn't do the `sed` command to change `deb` to `deb-src`.

Comment: You are building a shared library and naming it `Memory_Map_File.o`. Don't do _that_. Shared libraries are traditionally named `.so`.

Comment: That file is linked in.  For that you use a .o file (object file).  Shared objects are called differently.