# vfscanf.c No such file or directory

Tags: c

Learning malloc() from a book, I tried an example on the book. The following is the code of the exmaple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  double * ptd;
  int max;
  int number;
  int i=0;

  puts("how many double values will you enter?");
  if (scanf("%d",&max)!=1)
  {
    puts("Input not proper.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  ptd=(double *) malloc(max*sizeof(double));
  if (ptd=NULL)
  {
    puts("Failed to assign memory.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  puts("Enter values(q to exit)");
  while (i<max && scanf("%lf", ptd+i)==1) i++;

  printf("The following %d numbers are what you entered:\n",number=i);
  for (i=0; i<number; i++)
  {
    printf("%7.2f ",ptd[i]);
    if (i%7==6) putchar('\n');
  }

  if (i%7!=0) putchar('\n');
  free(ptd);
  puts("Bye!");
  return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled this with gcc and ran it. At first it seemed to be working properly, but when I entered double values(line 23, 24), the message of the line 26 didn't come out. So I debugged it by gdb and I encountered an error:

vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.

**EDIT** the following is input and result in gdb.

```
how many double values wil you enter?
5
Enter values(q to exit)
1.2 2.3 3.4 4.5 5.6

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a6a4cf in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>,
    format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffe0a8,
    errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:2444
2444    vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

[The possible duplicate in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955609/include-source-code-of-malloc-c-in-gdb) doesn't seem to address my problem.

What does the error mean and how can I solve this?

Comment: It just means that gdb couldn't find the relevant source file from the C standard library. Since the bug is most likely in your own code then you probably don't need to step through the standard library source code anyway, so you can just ignore this warning.

Comment: go up the stack until you find some source of yours.

Comment: Here's clearly a good time to put a space before the format specifier to `scanf()`, to eat any whitespace that otherwise hangs around in the buffer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a example of input that triggers the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug in your code is here:

```
if (ptd=NULL)
```

Instead of testing for the success of the preceding call to `malloc` you are instead setting `ptd` to `NULL`, which then later results in a crash when you try to dereference the pointer. Either your book has a mistake or you made a mistake when copying out the code - this line should of course be:

```
if (ptd == NULL)
```

NOTE: if you had enabled compiler warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) then the compiler would have pointed this out to you and saved you a lot of grief. ALWAYS enable compiler warnings, and ALWAYS pay attention to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I keep your advice in mind.

Comment: But how does 'ptd=NULL' cause the error? It seems there is no relation between them.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between `=` and `==`. `=` is *assignment*, `==` is *comparison*. After allocating `ptd` with `malloc` you then immediately set it to `NULL`, instead of comparing it with `NULL`.

Comment: Of course I know = is not comparison. What I want to know is how `ptd=NULL` cause **vfscanf.c** error.

Comment: I have explained this already - you set `ptd` to `NULL` - what do you think happens next ? Is `ptd` a valid pointer to your allocated memory now ? What will happen in the call to `scanf` when you try to store a value at `ptd+i` ?