# How do I read the source code for a C library in CLion

Tags: c, clion

- OS: Deepin 20 (base on Debian 10)
- CLion: 2020.1.2
- GCC: gcc (Uos 8.3.0.3-3+rebuild) 8.3.0
- Make: 4.2.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
- Cmake: 3.18.1

I am a newcomer who just started learning C language. When I was writing C code using CLion, I could access it by `Ctrl + mouse click` .

I'm calling the method inside the header function. For example, if I use `printf` , I can access the `stdio.h` file, which can be seen at line 332 `extern int printf (const char * ___, RESTRICT, format,...) ;` .

But if I want to see the details of this method

I can't see it. According to [Navigate in the code structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clion-quick-start-guide.html#code-structure)

Use `Ctrl+Alt+Home` to switch. But the IDE prompts `No related file` .

How can I get the source code to call a method? I want to learn from the good experiences of others by looking at their implementation logic in their libraries

Thank you for your review. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: The C standard library is not usually shipped with source code. Details of getting the source code and the debug info are compiler- and operating-system specific... yet your question does not mention even your operating system.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you for your reply. I add my operating system environment, i use deepin 20 (base on Debian 10) , and use gcc 8.2. Is there any way to look up the source code of the C standard Library? Or where you can see the relevant information, like the API manual or API reference,I have been trying to learn socket programming recently, but I don't know a lot about API, and I really want to know their internal logic, such as `htonl` in `netinet/in.h`.

Comment: Ok, now the question is so much better! With Debian-based distros it should be easy to get the source tarballs, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955609/include-source-code-of-malloc-c-in-gdb could work; but that's 5 years old and for Ubuntu of that time, but that is a good starting point.

Comment: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/master/libcxx/src

Comment: @huagang: what kind of program are you coding? Is it open source? If yes, where is the source code?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitchHello, I am just a beginner. I am still learning the basics of C language and looking for the best practices of using C language.I don't think I can write open source style code on my current basis.But I will study hard, and I will contribute to the open source community in the future. Thank you.

Comment: My advice: **contribute to some *existing* open source project coded in C**. You'll learn a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if most of GNU/Linux software is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), it is not installed (in source code form) by default on your computer.

Regarding C programming, see [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) (and the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/%7Evlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf)) and read the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), or simpler ones like [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/) or [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCC)), your linker (probably [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)), your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or [cmake](https://cmake.org/)). Enable all warnings and [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug info, so if using  [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with at least `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`; then improve your C code to get no warnings. Once you have debugged your C source code (using [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and perhaps [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)), add optimization flags such as `-O2`. Order of arguments to `gcc` matters!

Consider, for some tasks, generating some of your C code (perhaps some `#include`-d header file) with tools like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/), [SWIG](https://swig.org/), [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), [GUILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/), [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) - or your own program or script.

> I want to learn from the good experiences of others by looking at their implementation logic in their libraries

## You need to fetch the source code from elsewhere.

For examples, see [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or  [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/), and the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/) (and others: [GTK](https://gtk.org/), [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/), [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/), [GUILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), etc.... including many open source programs mentionned in this answer) and look also on websites like [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/), [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/)

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). See also http://linuxfromscratch.org/

In 2020, a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler happens to handle specially calls to `printf` when asked to optimize. See the [softwareheritage](https://softwareheritage.org/) and [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) projects.

In some cases, consider accepting [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugin) in your program with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) (see also [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)). You might even generate some code at runtime with libraries like [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) (or generate C code at runtime, then compile it as a plugin, and load it; such an approach is called [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) and is related to [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation); see also the [blog of the late J.Pitrat](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) for more insights).

Of course, you need tools to navigate in source code. Consider using [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) combined with [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) for that, or some other [source navigator.](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/) For large programs of millions of source code lines, consider writing your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to understand them.

Use also tools like [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the dynamic behavior of programs.

## Expect several months of full time work to explore all this.

You could be interested by [ACM](https://www.acm.org/) conference papers also.

For your own source code, consider using some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) tool such as [git](https://git-scm.com/). Of course read its documentation. And use [LibreOffice](https://libreoffice.org/), [Lout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_(software)) or [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), [MarkDown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (perhaps combined with [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) or [diagrams](https://www.diagrams.net/) for figures) to write the documentation of your software.

In some cases, you might consider generating parts of the documentation from parts of your source code (e.g. using [literate programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) techniques like [nuweb](http://nuweb.sourceforge.net/) or documentation generators like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, which also provided a lot of information, which is very helpful for me to explore the C language world.

Comment: These days I'd think that if it's not in markdown with occasional embedded TeX for math, then it may as well not be there. Word-derived word processors are pretty work-intensive to maintain any semblance of consistent style - whereas markdown makes it trivial. Markdown has widely available tooling support and most importantly github does a good job rendering it, as does gitlab, whereas `.doc` and `.odt` files are pretty much binary blurbs, while `.pdf` is viewable but barely (you need a local download + viewer to see contents/bookmarks at the very least).

Comment: Inkscape is great for figures, but diagrams.net (née draw.io) does an OK job for plenty of basic figures.