# Problems debugging with gdb

Tags: c++, c, linux, arm, gdb

I have a simple hello world program (Does not matter what program it is the results are the same). I compile the program with the -g flag. I run the executable it works fine, then I try to debug it and 8/10 times I get a segfault error, gdb can't find a source file.

First this isn't a duplicate of this: [Include source code of malloc.c in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955609/include-source-code-of-malloc-c-in-gdb), nothing there solves my problem.

I say 8 out of 10 times because at times it works just fine as it is supposed to, then it's back to the errors.

I don't get a segmentation fault, when I run the actual program. No errors, the error occurs only when I use the gnu debugger, and this is what it usually says:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.cpp:4
4               std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S:94
94      ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt 
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S:94
#1  0x0000007ff7f4ee58 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0000005555555a00 in main () at hello.cpp:4
```

Code: (A basic hello world program)

```
#include <iostream>
  
int main () {
        std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

This could be a malfunction from my system or problems with gdb. I am using a Chromeos arm64 arch. which has support for linux (debian Buster). Gdb version: GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1.

If I do load a source file (with the dir command), it happens to be some C code internals or even assembly and I still get a Segmentation fault, here I get a segmentation fault at a load command:

```
GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "aarch64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from helloCpp...done.
(gdb) dir /usr/src/glibc/glibc-2.28/sysdeps/aarch64/
Source directories searched: /usr/src/glibc/glibc-2.28/sysdeps/aarch64:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x9ec: file hello.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/name/helloCpp 

Breakpoint 1, main () at hello.cpp:4
4               std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S:94
94              ldp     data1, data2, [srcin]
(gdb) bt 
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S:94
#1  0x0000007ff7f4ee58 in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x0000005555555a00 in main () at hello.cpp:4
(gdb)
```

Running the actual program works just fine in C and in C++:

```
name@penguin:~$ ./helloCpp
hello world
name@penguin:~$ ./helloC
hello world
```

Comment: Please include the line starting with "This GDB was configured as "

Comment: If you type `c` iinstead of `n` to gdb, do you still get a segfault?

Comment: @stark I have added that.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes, the exact same result

Comment: It briefly worked normally for a moment, then just hanged. Stopping with Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+C didn't work. I had to close the terminal, I have tried reinstalling gdb/gcc/g++ many times, didn't work.

Comment: I honestly do not know if this is relevant or not, but the implementation of `strlen` (actually, probably `__strlen` to which `strlen` is weakly aliased) in "sysdeps/aarch64/strlen.S" was rewritten for glibc-2.32 to be "Arm MTE compatible" (see the [commitdiff](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=a365ac45b7b51dbd9dc65629203cc2a9603420bb) for details).

Comment: If you run it under gdb without setting any breakpoints at all, do you still get a segfault?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It works intermittently, it's working for now, after my system crashed, I rebooted my pc and everything is working as it should. I don't know if this is permanent or not, but it is working well for now, with or without breakpoints.

Comment: Consider using `si` [or `s`] instead of `n`. You can display registers and the current [asm] instruction. arm isn't as well developed as x86, so it _may_ be an issue with `gdb`. You may wish to do `disassemble strlen` to see the context of the instruction that is segfaulting. Then, you can compare what register values are wrong [and where they came from]. You could add a dummy statement after the hello world line. Or, put a breakpoint on the `return` in `main` (e.g. `return 0`) which you currently don't have. I assume you're compiling with `-g -O0`.

Comment: @CraigEstey no just -g.

Comment: Nothing your program does should _crash_ the _system_. Only segfault your program. If you don't specify _any_ `-O`, it is equivalent to `-O0`. If your system is working correctly after reboot, it may have been a fluke. Something unrelated to your program put the system in a "funny state". Try your program [with `n`] several times to see if the issue reoccurs--otherwise, don't worry--be happy.

Comment: @CraigEstey Actually it has been this way, for a few days now. It works fine for a while and goes back to segfaulting. Hopefully this is permanent, the last time debugging it did not segfault it just hung, no input resumed operation. I had to restart. This undefined behavior seems to be a system issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the chromeos arches. I have some experience with other arm arches (e.g. raspberry pi and nVidia jetson). You may want to try another arm system for comparison. arm [holdings] gives out the firmware for the CPU/arch but the issue may be with the additional H/W logic that the chip vendor adds (e.g. a bug in that H/W or the platform specific OS code). Or, the version of the arm arch (e.g. cortex-v8) has a known errata.

Comment: arm debug isn't as clean as x86. I don't think you're encountering this, but stepping across `stdatomic.h` primitives in arm is bad. In x86, it does it with a `lock` prefix on a single inst. For arm, it steps across a `ldrex` followed by `strex` pairing. The stepping "breaks" the atomic memory reserve that `ldrex` asserts and the `strex` will always fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228122/discussion-between-n00b-and-craig-estey).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is that you do not have
return 0;
in the last line of your program. I have an idea that a
return 0;
is not needed for C, but is for C++.