# x86_64 assembly call on fscanf segfaults. gdb shows vscanf_internal.c: no such file or directory

Tags: assembly, scanf, x86-64

```
.file "readlines.s"
# Assembler directives to allocate storage for static array
.section .rodata

fscanf_format_str:
.string "%d%d"

.globl readlines
.type readlines, @function

.text 
readlines:
    push %rbp           # save caller's %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp     # copy %rsp to %rbp so our stack frame is ready to use
    
    # store parameters on stack
    subq $-24, %rsp
    movq %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movl %edx, -20(%rbp)

    # using fscanf tp read entire while
    # set index
    movl $0, -24(%rbp)
loop_body:
    # if the number of real lines read by function is larger than expected, then break
    movl -20(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl %eax, -24(%rbp)
    jge exit

    # using fscanf to read line by line
    movq -8(%rbp), %rdi
    movq $fscanf_format_str, %rsi
    # get the target address
    movq -16(%rbp), %rdx
    movslq -24(%rbp), %rax
    imulq $16, %rax
    leaq 12(%rdx, %rax), %rdx
    movq -16(%rbp), %rcx
    leaq (%rcx, %rax), %rcx
    movq $0, %rax
    call fscanf
    # if fscanf return 0, then no line exists
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je exit
    
    # do arithmetic on the two values read from file
    movq -16(%rbp), %rdx
    movslq -24(%rbp), %rax
    imulq $16, %rax
    movslq (%rdx, %rax), %r8
    movslq 12(%rdx, %rax), %r9
    addq %r8, %r9
    movq %r9, 4(%rdx, %rax)
    
    incq -24(%rbp)
    jmp loop_body 
exit:
    leave
    ret
.size readlines, .-readlines
```

The above code is a simple function called readlines, which serves for reading two integers line by line from an input file, but fscanf shows SIGSEGV fault in gdb, see below picture for details:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, the picture was wrong. The <error: Cannot access...> is not the main reason which causes the SIGSEGV, because I uploaded a wrong picture. In fact, even if <error> does not happen, the No such file or directory also exists.

Comment: You don't need source code to debug the libc asm, if you want to see what instruction was actually faulting inside the libc function you called.  Use `layout asm` or `layout reg`, or use GDB's `disas`.  But since you originally titled this just with the GDB warning, not even asking about the segfault in your question title, I added [Include source code of malloc.c in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29955609) as an extra duplicate about how to install debug symbols / source for glibc under some distros.