# RPC: how to exit svc_run() on macOS?

Tags: linux, macos, rpc

I have a simple **ONC RPC server** in a helper thread. My **C/C++** application is to be ported to Linux, macOS, and Windows (planned, via MinGW-w64). The RPC server is running and tested on Linux and macOS; the problem is that I can't find any way to stop the helper thread on macOS: `svc_run()` is stuck in `__select_nocancel`, and, true to its name, I have found no way to cancel it.

Here's what I've tried:

- Replace `svc_run()` with [my own select loop](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libinfo/Libinfo-78.2/rpc.subproj/svc_run.c.auto.html), with the addition of [the self-pipe trick](https://lwn.net/Articles/177897/). This works great, on macOS as well as Linux, but, for reasons unknown, the RPC dispatcher `svc_getreqset()` doesn't call my service (neither Linux nor macOS).
- Call `pthread_cancel()` on the thread (works on Linux, not on macOS).
- Call `pthread_kill()` to send SIGUSR1 to the thread (works on Linux, not on macOS).
- Send myself a special RPC call via localhost, and have the server terminate itself upon reception (worked on Linux, not on macOS, but it was too complicated anyway).

I'm open to any and all suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution (custom `select()` loop with the self-pipe trick to quit) clearly seemed the best solution, so I focused on figuring out what was going wrong with `svc_getreqset()`.

The method is probably more interesting than the result: in Ubuntu, I [installed the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955609/include-source-code-of-malloc-c-in-gdb) for `glibc`, which contains the RPC stuff. Then I was able to use the debugger to trace into `svc_run()` and see what it was doing differently from my custom `select()` loop.

The answer turns out to be simple (of course): when we get a connection request on the RPC service transport (`SVCXPRT` structure), the first thing it does is create a new service transport for the socket returned by the `accept()` call. That then needs to be included in the `select()` in order to actually read the request. I wasn't doing that. Duh.