# What's wrong with my generic quick sort?

Tags: c, quicksort

I am trying to write a generic quicksort:

```
void _qsort(void *ptr, 
        size_t lrange, 
        size_t rrange,
        size_t size,
        int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if (lrange < rrange) {
        size_t i, j;
        void *key;

        key = malloc(size);
        i = lrange;
        j = rrange;
        memcpy(key, ptr + i * size, size);
        while (i < j) {
            while (i < j && (*cmp)(ptr + j * size, key) > 0)
                j--;
            if (i < j) {
                memcpy(ptr + i * size, ptr + j * size, size);
                i++;
            }
            while (i < j && (*cmp)(key, ptr + i * size) > 0)
                i++;
            if (i < j) {
                memcpy(ptr + j * size, ptr + i * size, size);
                j--;
            }
        }
        memcpy(ptr + i * size, key, size);
        _qsort(ptr, lrange, i - 1, size, cmp);
        _qsort(ptr, i + 1, rrange, size, cmp);
    }
}
```

I write a simple test on a int array, this is the cmp funciton:

```
int cmp(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    return *(int *)x - *(int *)y;
}
```

It cause a core dump, but when I change the type of `lrange, rrange, i, j` from `size_t` to `int`, it run right, I can't understand, why?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c) to better understand what is `size_t` and why it causes a crash. HINT: it's probably due to memcpy operating with it. but you're close.

Comment: Why don't you debug the core dump?

Comment: There is a problem when i debug this core dump, "malloc.c: No such file or directory."

Comment: @protream What compiler, what debugger? Did you include `<stdlib.h>` where malloc is located?

Comment: gdb. Seems same to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220853/call-to-malloc-failing-in-gdb-session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
size_t i, j;
```

are unsigned types. If a value of an unsigned variable is 0, and 1 is subtracted, the value will wrap-around to the largest possible value for that unsigned type.

This can happen on lines:

```
j--;
```

and:

```
_qsort(ptr, lrange, i - 1, size, cmp);
```

When that invalid value used as an index for an array, it will cause a seg-fault as the program cannot read an address that is out-of-bounds.

---

Do not use names with the prefix `_`, `_qsort`, as those are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @protream Make sure you never wrap a value, or use signed types. (Don't forget to rename those functions.)

Comment: @protream That is explained in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
memcpy(key, ptr + i * size, size);
```

`ptr` is a `void *`, you can't use pointer arithmetic with `void *`, switch to `char *` (as `qsort` in the standard library).

Comment: Nicely spotted. To avoid goof-up like this, use a standard compliant compiler. For example `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors // gives excellent C compiler` rather than `gcc // gives non-standard crapiler`